# What is the most random Markov martingale?

Tags: randomness, kolmogorov-complexity

Consider a boxing match between players A and B. If A wins, then $1$ point is gained; otherwise $1$ point is lost. Assume that $A$ is as same good as B. Denote by $X_t$ the expected point of A at time $t$, then the assumption means that $(X_t)_{0\le t\le T}$ is a Markov martingale. The match ends if either of the two conditions below is satisfied

1. One player KO (knockouts) the other and the match is interrupted immediately;
2. No KO occurs before time $T$ and the match ends at $$.

According to the above rules and our assumption, one has $X_0=0$ and $X_T\in\{-1,1\}$. My question is what is the most exciting game? More precisely, if you agree with me that "exciting"$\approx$"random", then my question can be reformulated as what is the most random Markov martingale?

Any answer, comments or references are highly appreciated!

PS: It is known that entropy is largely accepted to quantify randomness of random variables, while for stochastic processes, I do not find such an index. I am working in applied mathematics and got a comment of "none" to my question [How to quantify the randomness of martingales?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406733/how-to-quantify-the-randomness-of-martingales): ***For a discrete time process, randomness can be measured by Kolmogorov's complexity or the like. Beyond that, there is a theory of algorithmic randomness that belongs more to logic than probability theory, discussed in the book "Algorithmic Randomness and Complexity" by Downey and Hirschfeldt***. I have no idea at all in the domain and I hope to get some help here.

Comment: Entropy. Think of $X_0,\ldots,X_T$ as one big random variable.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for the reply. It appears that we can only define the "relative entropy" of a generic random variable, unless this random variable is discrete or absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Do you mean we assume further $X_0,\ldots, X_T$ are discrete or admit a joint density?

Comment: Your random variable is discrete, since each element is an integer (and also bound). It even has finite support. There is absolutely no problem in defining entropy.

Comment: Not really. Indeed, except for $X_0$ and $X_T$, all the intermediate random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_{T-1}$ can take any values in $[-1,1]$

Comment: Instead of looking at the expectations, you can look at the match results, which are discrete.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks a lot for your comments which I find very inspiring. Do you mind specify a bit your idea? Feel free to write it as an answer below. I do wish to know the viewpoints from the community of computer science. Thank you very much

Comment: What is exciting sounds like a matter of opinion.  How do you define "most random"?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/406733/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145981/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Please pick one site where you want the question to appear and let us know what that site is; and update the question on that site based on the feedback you have received on both sites.  Thank you!

Comment: It appears that you copied a [comment posted elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406733/how-to-quantify-the-randomness-of-martingales#comment1043203_406733) without attribution.  We require you to provide proper credit for the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: @D.W. I am not sure whether I completely understand what you mean. I have claimed in this post that I do not receive any satisfying answer of my question in math overflow, and inspired by a comment, I would like to know more details that are quite specific for the community of computer science

Comment: You have asked the same question on both sites.  That violates Stack Exchange policy, as described at the link I listed.  You can read there to understand better.  This post does not appear to have a narrow scope of details that are specific to computer science; rather, it asks the same question as on Math Overflow ("what is the most random Markov martingale?").  Also, "I have no idea at all in the domain and I hope to get some help here" is not a specific, focused question.  I suggest that you pick one site where you want this question to appear.